# optimizing jQuery Selectors - Which is faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, performance

Are selectors or functions faster in jQuery?  Example:

```
$('#something div.else'); // find multiple divs with class .else
```

or

```
$('#something').children('div.else');
```

I'm trying my best to optimize a page with hundreds of returned elements that seems to hang on a certain crappy computer here in the office (that must use Internet Explorer ::shudder::).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in this case, the second's faster, **but**, they're not equivalent.  The first finds *any* descendant `div.else`, the other finds only *direct* children that are `div.else`.

It depends on your DOM as to which is faster, the equivalent of the second would be this:

```
$('#something > div.else');
```

This uses the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).  They should be *very*, **very** close, and in any case, I doubt a selector descending from an ID is your problem area, I think you'll find the vast majority of your time in JS is spent elsewhere.

For diagnosing speed issues, get a profiler, for IE specifically there's a fantastic free one called [dynaTrace AJAX Edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/).  Grab it, [follow the short tutorials](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/learn/solution-tour/ajax-performance-diagnostics.aspx) on their site...you'll find where your pain areas in IE are pretty quickly.

Comment: jQuery will translate such a call into `$('#something').find('div.else')`.

Comment: @jAndy - No, it won't.  Sizzle != jQuery they are separate, it [uses Sizzle](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/sizzle-jquery.js).  The *effect* is the same, but it doesn't make that call.  If you're meaning it's equivalent...well, again no, `.children() != .find()`.

Comment: well, I just expressed myself wrong. Sizzle will detect if the first thing within the selector string is an id, and then sizzle converts it into the `find` statement. But anyway, its in the jQuery source, so.. I never stated `.children() === .find()` anyways

Comment: @jAndy - Fair enough, though I'm *really* confused as to what "such a call" means if you weren't referring to my answer or the question...because neither have any code that get translated that way.

Comment: indeed that was confusing, should be `Sizzle will optimize $('#something div.else') into $('#something').find('div.else)`.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't checked with the jQuery code, I think the difference should be negligable between your two examples - although the first one should run a little faster.

The problem with old IE versions is that they do not support a native way to fetch items based on class names. In this case, jQuery has to execute a regulra expression on each class attribute of each element contained.

If it is possible in your case, you might gain quite a lot performance when being able to select on an unusual tagname:

```
$("#container blockquote.else")
```

and ideally,leave away the class name.

EDIT: just saw the answer from Nick and he's right, the scond one only has to check the direct children. The equivalent first one would be:

```
$("#container > div.else")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example, your first example of

```
$('#something div.else');
```

gets optimized through `Sizzle` (which is delivered within the jQuery lib) into

```
$('#something').find('div.else');
```

without that optimization, it **would** be slower, since the selector engine `sizzle` does work from **right** to **left**. So, it would match all `divs` with the class `else` and would then check which of those has `#something` as parent.

**edit**

> The `Sizzle optimazation` is slower
>   anyway, since it took a while until
>   that task is completed and some
>   functions are called on the way

In general, using `jQuery functions` is a lot faster. For instance jQuerys `.eq()` function will use an `array slice` to reduce a wrappet set of jQuery objects, whereas `:eq()` selector will invoke sizzle.

If in your example, `div.else` elements are direct children of `#something`, `.children()` will beat `.find()` since `.find()` will also lookup **all** descendants (and their childs).

Comment: jQuery does not make this optimization, it passes the selector to sizzle.  `$('#something div.else');` gets turned into `$(document).find('#something div.else');`, not `$('#something').find('div.else');`.  jQuery doesn't tinker with selectors like this.

Comment: @Nick: well, I just expressed myself wrong. Sizzle will detect if the first thing within the selector string is an id, and then sizzle converts it into the `find` statement. But anyway, its in the jQuery source, so..

Comment: It's not "in the source", it's *built* with jQuery, but Sizzle itself is a separate project, and included in a few libraries, you can find its source here: http://github.com/jeresig/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js  As for the convert, it doesn't matter what the first of the string is, any space split (not including a special selector, e.g. `>`) is a `.find()`: http://github.com/jeresig/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L88

Comment: When you're talking about performance and optimization? **Absolutely**, where things happen matter a great deal in this context.  Normally it wouldn't matter a bit because the difference is so infinitesimal, but when you're talking about *performance*, it relates directly to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need the fastest way to get `#something div.else` in IE6. Since jQuery uses Sizzle, the way it will find that is first find all `div`'s, then filter by the ones with the `else` class, and has an ancestor with the `#something` id.

Your second example will be faster if it contains few children, slower if it contains many.

A suggestion you could try would be to use another tag type instead of `div`, one that isn't used in your page, say `blockquote`. Just reset it's styles with css so it looks like a normal div, then change your selector to `#something blockquote.else` which should be tons faster.